# Compile PHP without PostgreSQL

Tags: linux, php, php5

I need to compile php-5.2.17 as a cgi wrapper. PostgreSQL is not installed on this machine. I'm looking for the configure command, to **disable support for PostgreSQL**.

> --without-postgre

Comment: You really do not want to run PHP 5.2. It's way past its shelf life...

Comment: I don't feel happy about it. But you need to support obsolete frameworks sometimes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you [Read The Friendly Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php)?

Admittedly I don't see where it explicitly tells you how to configure without postgresql support - but since it tells you how to add postgresql support, that rather implies it's disabled by default

```
In order to enable PostgreSQL support, --with-pgsql[=DIR] is required when you compile
```

do you have anything to suggest that's not the case?

Further, since postgresql support is described by `pgsql` it seems likely that should it be necessary to explicitly disable it then, at a guess the config option would be:

```
--without-pgsql
```

Is there a reason you want to compile the code yourself? Unless you link PHP statically, it's simply a matter of commenting out the extensions you don't need from the `php.ini` file to disable them.